# Pip3 is not working Python 3.10 for pandas installation

Tags: pandas, pip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install pandas library for python with pip but I get this error. I don't understand how to fix, can someone help me?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ pip3 install pandas

Collecting pandas==1.3.0                                                                                   Using cached pandas-1.3.0.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1350 lines of output]

[...] 1000 lines of stuff

rgument is of type ‘npy_longdouble *’ {aka ‘double *’}
             __MATHCALL (modf,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__iptr)) __nonnull ((2));
             ^
            error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
-fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_CBLAS -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=-1 -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.10/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.10/build/src.linux-armv7l-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
            [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: as the error says, this is probably not related to pip. It seems more likely to me that you're missing libraries on your system to run some part of the build (e.g. `python3-dev`, `gcc`, `libc-dev`, `build-essential` etc.)

Comment: @FObersteiner is there a list somewhere?

Comment: good question, that depends on your platform so I doubt there are lists which work in general. Maybe installing pandas via apt is an option for you; `apt install python3-pandas` ?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc usefull article thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install numpy first in case you had an incompatible version?

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: It is alrady installed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code instead of pip3 install pandas

1. pip install pandas

or

2. pip install pandas=1.4.4